# How to avoid "chunked" Transfer-Encoding?

Tags: apache

How to avoid chunked Transfer-Encoding ? Is there any benefit with this encoding?

Below is what appears as part of Apache Web Server (V2.4) header message:

```
Connection:  Keep-Alive
Content-Type:    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding:    gzip
Transfer-Encoding:   chunked
```

Comment: If you don't even know what it is, why do you want to avoid this value for it? And what other value do you want? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chunked transfer encoding is an HTTP/1.1 feature that enables keep-alive requests.

If you want to avoid chunked encoding send requests to the server using HTTP/1.0.   A request with HTTP/1.0 would look like this

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.com
```

The problem with HTTP/1.0 is that it required a new connection for each resource downloaded.  Since each html document contains many images, CSS, and JS files, you might need tens of connection to download an entire page using HTTP/1.0.  Establishing each connection is slow.  When HTTP/1.1 was invented, a design goal was to allow pipelining and re-use of connections, even when the size of a document is not known when delivery of it is started.

Now browsers can download the page and all of its images in a single connection.  The web server responds in "chunks".  Each chunk starts with the size of the chunk.  A single document have an unlimited number of chunks and the server doesn't need to know the size of the entire document to start sending out the first chunk. Once that first chunk has been downloaded, more chunks can be sent over the same connection until the document is complete.  Then the connection can be re-used.

On the server side, most programatic APIs for building web pages use chunked encoding by default.  That is so the developer can dynamically build a page and start sending it as it is built.   Chunked encoding adds a small amount of overhead in terms of document size, but allows for a lower time to first byte.  Without chunked encoding the server would have to wait for the script to produce the whole document.  It would have to buffer it (in memory or on disk), calculate the entire document size, and then send it all at once to be able to re-use the connection afterwards.

You may be able to avoid chunked encoding even with HTTP/1.1 from the server side by calculating sizes up front.   Static documents often don't use chunked encoding because their size is fixed.   Dynamic documents may be able to avoid chunked encoding by having the script set the `Content-Length` header when starting to send the document.